# Apache mina-sshd ssh client always prints EdDSA provider not supported

Tags: java, ssh, apache-mina

I'm using Apache sshd's ssh client. Whenever I establish a connection to the destination ssh server, I see this in the logs. The connection works, but is there something wrong? How can I fix it?

The exception looks like:

```
(SshException) to process: EdDSA provider not supported
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**How to fix**

To fix the problem add a dependency net.i2p.crypto:eddsa. Bouncy castle does not provide the implementation of EdDSA. For example in maven add this dependency:

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>net.i2p.crypto</groupId>
       <artifactId>eddsa</artifactId>
       <version>0.3.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

**Impact of not fixing**

If you don't fix this, then you will not be able to validate the host keys. My testing was not impacted because I was not validating the host keys yet. However, once deployed to production, I would have been impacted because host keys must be validated.

**Details**

In the Apache mina-sshd source code, the class [SecurityUtils](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/af6c8eddd897e18e8834c6439c48513cec150c8c/sshd-common/src/main/java/org/apache/sshd/common/util/security/SecurityUtils.java) reveals the problem. That class hardcodes the provider for EdDSA to `EdDSASecurityProviderRegistrar` :

```
public static final List<String> DEFAULT_SECURITY_PROVIDER_REGISTRARS = Collections.unmodifiableList(
        Arrays.asList(
                "org.apache.sshd.common.util.security.bouncycastle.BouncyCastleSecurityProviderRegistrar",
                "org.apache.sshd.common.util.security.eddsa.EdDSASecurityProviderRegistrar"));
```

Looking through [EdDSASecurityProviderRegistrar](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/e021a6f4597cb7259162169851bb9e4cb85e1a39/sshd-common/src/main/java/org/apache/sshd/common/util/security/eddsa/EdDSASecurityProviderRegistrar.java) you see that it expects the class `net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.EdDSAKey` to exist:

```
@Override
public boolean isSupported() {
    Boolean supported;
    synchronized (supportHolder) {
        supported = supportHolder.get();
        if (supported != null) {
            return supported.booleanValue();
        }

        ClassLoader cl = ThreadUtils.resolveDefaultClassLoader(getClass());
        supported = ReflectionUtils.isClassAvailable(cl, "net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.EdDSAKey");
        supportHolder.set(supported);
    }

    return supported.booleanValue();
}
```

A quick google search and you'll see that `net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.EdDSAKey` is provided by the library net.i2p.crypto:eddsa.

Comment: Awesome, this solution removed that warning!