# Apache SSHD client unverified EC key warnings on camel route

Tags: apache-camel, apache-sshd

I have a camel route that uses the ssh component provided by camel through the dependency import via `implementation("org.apache.camel:camel-ssh")`, i think this basically pacakges up the apache sshd client. So, what I was wondering was how to remove this error from popping up every time the camel route is ran:

```
2021-08-16 10:20:37.075  WARN --- [] org.apache.sshd.client.keyverifier.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier : Server at /XX.XXX.XXX.XX:22 presented unverified EC key: SHA256:XX/XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
2021-08-16 10:20:37.286  WARN --- [] org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientConnectionService : globalRequest(ClientConnectionService[ClientSessionImpl[user-acc@/XX.XXX.XXX.XX:22]])[hostkeys-00@openssh.com, want-reply=false] failed (SshException) to process: EdDSA provider not supported
```

it connects all fine, however, it just comes up with these warnings which i'd like to remove if possible.

Cheers,
Harrison

Comment: did you found any solution

Comment: For the second warning ("EdDSA provider not supported") check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65566138/apache-mina-sshd-ssh-client-always-prints-eddsa-provider-not-supported.


And for the first warning ("presented unverified EC key"), it looks like you are allowing unknown keys therefore it will be always logged - we can see in the implementation: https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/master/sshd-core/src/main/java/org/apache/sshd/client/keyverifier/StaticServerKeyVerifier.java#L59
You would need to configure known host keys (known_hosts).